# Moles with SOCKS?

Tags: code-golf, networking

Many applications that depend on network resources (such as games connecting to game servers) do not allow the user to set a proxy. There are a lot of ways to force the usage of a proxy regardless, I personally have always been a fan of a **local SOCKS tunnel.**

### What's that?

Instead of connecting directly, an application on your local machine listens on a locally bound address and *relays* any connection to a fixed endpoint using a remote SOCKS proxy.

Example: Let our target be 11.22.33.44:5555, and our remote socks proxy be 99.88.77.66:5555. Our application listens on 127.0.0.1:5555. Our route now looks like this:

*connect to* **127.0.0.1:5555** - *relays via SOCKS proxy* > **99.88.77.66:5555** - *to* > **11.22.33.44:5555**

Your goal is to implement the local application relaying connections to the target.

### Input

Three address/port pairs representing the bind, proxy and target address.

- You may deviate from the order (but specify if you do).
- Address parsing is up to your language/tools of choice, but should at the very minimum support IPv4 (11.22.33.44).
- You may use builtin types of your language. (like `InetSocketAddress` in Java, `struct in_addr` in C, etc.)

### Output

No rules for output due to [networking](/questions/tagged/networking).

### Additional

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins.
- [Standard rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422) apply, [default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- You do not have to support more than 1 connection. The program may terminate after the first connection finishes.
- Program behaviour under network failures is undefined; you may crash the entire program, reject the incoming connection, do whatever you want.
- You may assume the remote SOCKS proxy's version (4/4a/5).
- Using libraries/inbuilts/etc. is encouraged, but not required.
- Stay in input scope (f.e. don't proxy all connections on the machine).

Comment: So the task is to create a local SOCKS server that accepts local connections (e.g. from a suitably configured browser) and connects to a remote SOCKS proxy that forwards the connection to the far end (e.g. web server)? - its not entirely clear to me.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Not a local SOCKS server, but more a local tunnel server *using* a fixed SOCKS proxy to forward connections to a fixed end.

Comment: So just a simple local TCP port forward then?  - that itself knows nothing of the SOCKS protocol?  This is not really clear to me

Comment: I'm not sure what else there is to explain? From the point of the connecting application it is effectively a port forward. The impementing application obviously has to know about the SOCKS protocol. I've even given a sample answer in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin, 240 bytes

This was fun and taught me some things I didn't know about Kotlin.

```java
import java.net.*fun a(vararg p:InetSocketAddress){ServerSocket().run{bind(p[0])
accept().let{Socket(Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS,p[1])).run{connect(p[2])
Thread{it.inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)}.start()
inputStream.copyTo(it.outputStream)}}}}
```

Tested locally with:

```java
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    thread { a(InetSocketAddress(2000), InetSocketAddress(3000), InetSocketAddress(4000)) }
    thread { Socket().connect(InetSocketAddress(2000)) }
    ServerSocket(3000).accept().getInputStream().run { generateSequence { read() } }
            .forEach { print("$it,") }
}
```

Prints `5,2,0,2,` which confirms an attempted SOCKS5 connection.